# How can I slice a PyTorch tensor with another tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have:

```
inp =  torch.randn(4, 1040, 161)
```

and I have another tensor called `indices` with values:

```
tensor([[124, 583, 158, 529],
        [172, 631, 206, 577]], device='cuda:0')
```

I want the equivalent of:

```
inp0 = inp[:,124:172,:]
inp1 = inp[:,583:631,:]
inp2 = inp[:,158:206,:]
inp3 = inp[:,529:577,:]
```

Except all added together, to have a .size of `[4, 48, 161]`. How can I accomplish this?

Currently, my solution is a `for` loop:

```
            left_indices = torch.empty(inp.size(0), self.side_length, inp.size(2))
            for batch_index in range(len(inp)):
                print(left_indices_start[batch_index].item())
                left_indices[batch_index] = inp[batch_index, left_indices_start[batch_index].item():left_indices_end[batch_index].item()]
```

Comment: @Shanoon Did you want to stack all `inp_i`s or have them separately?

Comment: I want to stack them

Comment: My answer stacks them all. Final shape is `(4, 192, 161)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go (EDIT: you probably need to copy tensors to cpu using `tensor=tensor.cpu()` before doing following operations):

```
index = tensor([[124, 583, 158, 529],
    [172, 631, 206, 577]], device='cuda:0')
#create a concatenated list of ranges of indices you desire to slice
indexer = np.r_[tuple([np.s_[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(index[0,:],index[1,:])])]
#slice using numpy indexing
sliced_inp = inp[:, indexer, :]
```

Here is how it works:

`np.s_[i:j]` creates a slice object (simply a range) of indices from start=`i` to end=`j`.

`np.r_[i:j, k:m]` creates a list ALL indices in slices `(i,j)` and `(k,m)` (You can pass more slices to `np.r_` to concatenate them all together at once. This is an example of concatenating only two slices.)

Therefore, `indexer` creates a list of ALL indices by concatenating a list of slices (each slice is a range of indices).

UPDATE: If you need to remove interval overlaps and sort intervals:

```
indexer = np.unique(indexer)
```

if you want to remove interval overlaps but not sort and keep original order (and first occurrences of overlaps)

```
uni = np.unique(indexer, return_index=True)[1]
indexer = [indexer[index] for index in sorted(uni)]
```

Comment: Can you explain what `r_` and `s_` do?

Comment: @Shamoon I will add more explanation in a bit.

Comment: @Shamoon I just checked and you do not need to convert to numpy. These operations work on tensors too. I just edited the answer to tensors. If it works for you please accept to close it. Thank you.

Comment: I get `TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.`

Comment: @Shamoon I do not have `CUDA` so I used `cpu`. I guess you can copy `index` and `inp` to `cpu` using `index=index.cpu()` and `inp=inp.cpu()`. I am not sure how to do numpy operations on GPU.

Comment: There appear to be duplicates in `indexer`

Comment: @Shamoon Of course, because intervals `124:172` and `158:206` overlap. Do you want to remove duplicates and keep only the first occurrence? Note that here order matters also, do you also with to sort all intervals?

Comment: Fair point - what abut in certain cases where I have a negative value? Then it all blows up

Comment: @Shamoon I added both sorted/non-sorted overlap removal in the post. Could you please explain more? like you have negative values in`index` tensor? How do you wish to deal with them? convert negatives to 0 or remove that interval from intervals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211963/discussion-between-shamoon-and-ehsan).

Answer (score 2):

```
inp =  torch.randn(4, 1040, 161)   
indices = torch.tensor([[124, 583, 158, 529],
            [172, 631, 206, 577]])
k = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
for i,j in k:
    print(inp[:,i:j,:])
```

You can implement it like this ... zip function helps to convert your indices tensor to list of tuples which you can use directly via for loop

Hope it helps you out....

Comment: Can I avoid a loop somehow?

Comment: You wish to avoid for loop only... can while loop work out for you if used ?

Comment: @Shamoon I thought you want to stack them all together. If you want to loop and do not care about stacking them fast, you do not need to zip, just loop over indices. Something like: `for i in range(indices.shape[1]): print(inp[:,indices[0,i]:indices[1,i],:])`