# How can I create a tiled/stacked array based on ranges using these 2 input arrays - but without looping?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, range, vectorization

My basic problem is that I need to use 2 arrays with integers, and arrive at an combined array that is the combination of many ranges made using pairwise combinations from the 2 initial arrays.

Said slightly differently, I want to use 2 arrays, combine them to produce a set of ranges, and then merge these ranges together. Importantly, I need to do this without using any looping, as I am going to need to do this almost 4 million times.

My 2 starting arrays are:

```
import numpy as np
sd = np.array([3,3,4,2,5,1])   # StartDate
ed = np.array([4,5,5,5,8,2])   # EndDate
```

Pairwise, they would look like this, combining  (sd[i] with ed[i]):

```
[(3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (2, 5), (5, 8), (1, 2)]   # Pairwise combinations of StartDate and EndDate
```

By way of example, I *could* iterate over these pairs, creating  ranges, exemplifying below:

```
[In]: range1 = np.arange(3,4)
[Out]: array([3])
[In]: range2 = np.arange(3,5)
[Out]: array([3,4])
```

...and so on, to arrive at the final out put which would be:

```
array([3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1])  # End result where the arrays are tiled after one another 
#(note first 3 digits are array 1 and array 2 from immediately above.
```

My issue is that I need to go from the input arrays and to the output array without looping, as I have already tried a version of this, and it is WAY too slow.  Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: So your slices differ in length?  Why do you expect to do that with multidimensional array indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in luck. Here is a one liner solution:

```
indexer = np.r_[tuple([np.s_[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(sd,ed)])]
```

output:

```
[3 3 4 4 2 3 4 5 6 7 1]
```

[I have also explained similar case in here for torch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290634/4975981): "*Here is how it works:*

np.s_[i:j] creates a slice object (simply a range) of indices from start=i to end=j.

np.r_[i:j, k:m] creates a list ALL indices in slices (i,j) and (k,m) (You can pass more slices to np.r_ to concatenate them all together at once. This is an example of concatenating only two slices.)

Therefore, indexer creates a list of ALL indices by concatenating a list of slices (each slice is a range of indices)."

Comment: So you are concatenating the indices instead of the results of indexing.  I still see a `for`

Comment: Amazing - this solved my problem within an acceptable amount of time. Running on 3.8mn different ranges, it took

`Wall time: 32.8 s`

...for producing an output array of length 21mn.
`In[436]: len(indexer)`

`Out[437]: 21694120`

Thanks very much!

Comment: Great. Please go ahead and accept it if it solves your issue so others find it helpful. Thank you.